# NoMethodError in Rails when creating a new instance of model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model that depends from another model, I have specified it like this in my `routes.rb` file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :events do
    resources :guests
    get :whereabouts
  end
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
```

`models/event.rb`:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :guests
end
```

`models/guest.rb`:

```
class Guest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
end
```

When I access `http://localhost:3000/events/2/guests/` it works properly but when I access `http://localhost:3000/events/2/guests/new` I get

```
undefined method `guests_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000004074f78>:0x0000000aaf67c0>
```

from line #1 of my `views/guests/_form.html.erb` file which is

```
  <%= form_for(@guest) do |f| %>
  <% if @guest.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@guest.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this event from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @guest.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I changed the paths to the proper ones since now `guests_path` should be `event_guests_path`, but I don't know where to change it in my form for it to work properly.

Any clue? Is my routing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routing is correct. But the guest object depends from the event one so you have to change the form to:

```
<%= form_for [@event, @guest] do |f| %>
 ...
<% end %>
```

you must have initialized the @event variable in the controller where you probably did something like:

```
@event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
@guest = @event.guests.build
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for):

> For namespaced routes, like `admin_post_url`:
>
> ```
> <%= form_for([:admin, @post]) do |f| %>
>   ...
> <% end %>
> ```

So, in your case, you probably want this:

```
<%= form_for([:event, @guest]) do |f| %>
```